# Django Conditional User Profiles

Tags: django, django-signals, django-users

I am trying to implement multiple user roles in my Django app using a profile-like model linked to the User model. The intent is to enable/disable functionality based on the class of the linked profile.

I have read examples of using the post_save signal to create a user profile linked back to the User model. What I can't figure out is how to send the post_save signal from the User model to multiple receivers with a keyword or some other attribute to perform a conditional check against.

```
models.py
---------
class AgencyOwner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='owner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_owner(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created and kwargs.get("owner") is True: # This fails
            AgencyOwner.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.owner.save()
```

I don't know if this is the appropriate solution, I looked into Groups and permissions as well but I am unsure how to create them programmatically outside of the Django admin interface. The intent is to have the roles set either at account creation or possibly by a user with the 'is_staff' flag set to True.